# Node.js and expressjs routing to another folder

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express, npm

I need help with routing using ui.router.

My folder structure looks like this:

[image]

In my `app.js` under `javascripts` looks like this:

```
var app = angular.module('testing', ['ui.router']);

app.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
  $stateProvider
    .state('home', {
        url: '/home',
        templateUrl: '/home.html'
    })
    .state('client_form', {
        url: '/request',
        templateUrl: '/client.html',
        controller: 'MainCtrl'
    });

  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('home');
}]);
```

My `index.ejs` looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Testing</title>
        <link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.10/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.2.10/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
        <script src="/javascripts/app.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body ng-app="testing">

        <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
            <ui-view></ui-view>
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

`home.ejs`:

```
<div class="page-header text-center" style="font-size:45px">
  Hacker List
</div>

<div class="text-center">
    <a href="worker.html">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btnBig">Worker</button>
    </a>

    <br />

    <a href="Client.html">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btnBig">Client</button>
    </a>
</div>
```

When I do `npm start` and go to the website, I get an infinite loop of it not finding `home.html`.

I can make the code in `home.ejs` appear if I make it inline inside `index.ejs` using `<script type="text/ng-template" id="/home.html">HOME_CODE_HERE</script>`; however, I don't want to do that.

I'm not sure how to fix this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ui.router` is AngularJS, not NodeJS.
Probably the *infinite loop* problem is in your front-end, not in NodeJS routes.

Out of the AngularJS problem, I would say that Express routes are in the back-end, so after a request (from Angular, browser, link, redirection etc) the responsibility and configuration needed to work is in NodeJS + Express + EJS.

Let's say you make a request to your `/index.html`. Once the request gets in the back-end, NodeJS will assume how to handle it.

So, to make sure you don't have a problem in NodeJS, check your `app.js` (used in node - probably in the root of your project). It could have the routing config similar with this:

```js
var express = require('express');

var app = express();

// EJS template config
app.set('views','./views');
app.set('view engine','ejs');

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true })); //support x-www-form-urlencoded
app.use(bodyParser.json());

// This is your routes
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  // Your code for index
  res.render('views/index', { param : "This is a EJS test" });
});

app.get('/index.html', function(req, res) {
  // Your code for index
  res.render('views/index', { param : "This is a EJS test" });
});

app.get('/anotherPage.html', function(req, res) {
  // Your code for another page: can include validations here
  res.render('views/anotherPage', { param : "This is a EJS test" });
});
```

Now you would have your route set in NodeJS, then you could set your EJS files. Your `home.ejs` can be exactly the same.
The `index.ejs` file would be a little different. Maybe you could write it like this (I removed AngularJS from it for testing purposes):

```js
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Testing</title>
        <link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>

    <body>
        This is a parameter from the back-end: <%= param %>
        This is the index of EJS template. Below the snipped inserted:
        <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
               <% include home.ejs %>
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

There are some good examples about routes and EJS in Express github page:
https://github.com/expressjs/express/tree/master/examples

I think that eliminating the problem with NodeJS can help you to fix the problem that seems to be in AngularJS.

Hope it's somehow helpful.